how to delete null line in batch script from csv files
I had a problem with my csv files input, because some of csv type is not processed because process runner is NPE to automate insert with dataloader CLI. Can you have a solution with this problem?
This my batch script to handle csv files:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0

set "oldheader=NO,NO ANTRIAN,NO SPAJ,TIPE DOKUMEN,TGL KIRIM,KEY"
set "newheader=No Urut,BOX_NO,NoAntrian,NoPolis,Jenis Dokumen,Jenis Transaksi,Tgl Penerimaan,NoAntrian NB,Tgl Penerimaan NB,Key"
set "isOldFile=false"
set "destinationDir=D:\MyDir\toLoad"
set "outputFile=%destinationDir%\output.csv"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=," %%i in (%1) do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "line=%%i"
    
    if "!line!" EQU "!newheader!" (
        set "isOldFile=false"
        set /a lineNumber=!count!-1
        GOTO :NEWFILE
    )

    if "!line!" EQU "!oldheader!" (
        set "isOldFile=true"
        set /a lineNumber=!count!-1
        GOTO :OLDFILE
    )
)

:OLDFILE
echo count: %lineNumber%
echo %isOldFile%
for /f "skip=%lineNumber% usebackq tokens=* delims=," %%i in (%1) do (
    echo %%i >> %outputFile%
    echo %%i
)
GOTO :END

:NEWFILE
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=," %%i in (%1) do (
    echo %%i >> %outputFile%
    echo %%i
)
:END
echo END

When a csv file have an input like this:
79,30210150817,815-5178109,Dokumen SPAJ dan kelengkapannya,2015-10-02,156 - IMGO - 17000_30210150817_815-5178109
80,30210150826,515-8782994,Dokumen SPAJ dan kelengkapannya,2015-10-02,156 - IMGO - 17000_30210150826_515-8782994
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,

and processed with my script, the output result like this:
79,30210150817,815-5178109,Dokumen SPAJ dan kelengkapannya,2015-10-02,156 - IMGO - 17000_30210150817_815-5178109 
80,30210150826,515-8782994,Dokumen SPAJ dan kelengkapannya,2015-10-02,156 - IMGO - 17000_30210150826_515-8782994 
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.

How to remove null lines in csv with batch script, because ECHO is off. is cause of error when I run with dataloader CLI
SOLUTION
I use best answer from this question to solving problem.
